# Cписок меню и права на доступ Actions

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте.

У меня в проекте меню реализован, и сохранен в базе данных `MS SQL Server`. Каждый раз когда загружается новая страница, метод `getMenuItemAndSerialize()` извлекает из базы данных, и отображает на странице элементы меню соответственно по ролям .

Что бы каждый раз не извлекать данные из БД, я решил сохранить `List<some_object>` в *ASP.NET Session State*. Размер объекта сохраненный в сессии достигает максимум до 13 kb. Как думаете, 13 Kb не многовато для одной сессии?

Есть ли решение по лучше, и ссылки на реализацию?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А русское слово "разрешения" не более-ли подходит вместо слова "пермиссии"?

Comment: Я просто думал, слово Xэш тоже русского происхождение, поэтому продолжал в этом же духе. Замечание принял, отредактирую текст к лучшему ))

Answer (score 1):

С помощью кэширования вы можете уменьшить количество обращений к базе данных, оптимизировать обработку запросов и тем самым уменьшить нагрузку на сервер и повысить производительность.

Наиболее простой способ кэширования данных представляет использование атрибута **OutputCache**.

Данный атрибут может применяться как к всему контроллеру, так и к отдельным его методам. Применение атрибута к контроллеру позволяет задать единую политику кэширования ко всем методам данного контроллера.

Действие атрибута **OutputCache** можно настроить с помощью его свойств:

- **CacheProfle**: определяет конфигурацию кэширования
- **Duration**: продолжительность кэширования контента в секундах. Важно
  оптимально подобрать временной отрезок, так как если задать большое
  значение, то пользователи будут работать практически со статичными
  данными, а при очень маленьком значении будет слишком часто
  обновление кэша, что нивелирует преимущества его использования
- **Location**: место, где размещается кэшированный контент
- **NoStore**: если данное значение равно true, в ответе в заголовке
  Cache-Control устанавливается флаг no-store, что указывает браузеру,
  что контент не надо сохранять
- **SqlDependency**: определяет зависимость между кэшем и таблицой в бд
- **VaryByCustom**: указывает произвольное значение, по которому будут
  определяться различные версии кэшированных данных
- **VaryByHeader**: указывает на набор заголовков, по которым будут
  определяться различные версии кэшированных данных
- **VaryByParam**: указывает на параметры строки запроса или параметры
  переданных форм, по которым будут определяться различные версии
  кэшированных данных

С помощью свойства **Location** можно определить в качестве хранилища кэшированного контента как сервер, так и браузер клиента. В частности, данное свойство может принимать одно из значений перечисления System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation:

- **Any**: контент кэшируется как на клиенте, так и на прокси-сервере и в
  выходном кэше сервера
- **Client**: контент кэшируется на клиенте(в браузере)
- **Downstream**: контент кэшируется как на клиенте, так и на
  прокси-сервере. Выходной кэш сервера не используется
- **None**: для заголовка Cache-Control устанавливается значение no-cache,
  что значит, что контент не будет нигде кэшироваться
- **Server**: контент кэшируется только в выходном кэше сервера
- **ServerAndClient**: контент кэшируется на клиенте и в выходном кэше
  сервера

Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CachingApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        static int x = 9;

        [OutputCache(Duration=30, Location= OutputCacheLocation.Downstream)]
        public string Index()
        {
            x++;
            return x.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Для простоты примера в данном случае выводится в браузере значение статической переменной. При обычной работе без кэширования при каждом обращении к данному методу значение этой переменной увеличивалось бы на единицу. Но здесь используется атрибут OutputCache, который задает, во-первых, время кэширования - 30 секунд, во-вторых, место кэша - клиент и возвожные прокси-серверы, через которые может идти запрос.

В итоге несмотря на новые обращения к ресурсу в пределах 30 секунд мы будем получать одно и то же значение переменной x, потому что ее значение будет браться из кэша. И только через 30 секунд эта переменная может инкрементироваться.

Мы можем проинспектировать заголовки ответа в браузере (например, в IE):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При получении кэшированных данных мы получим статусный код 304, а затраченное на запрос время будет очень небольшим (в данном случае не более 1 мс), так как данные будут браться из кэша браузера.

Подобным образом мы можем ограничиться кэшированием на сервере:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    static int x = 9;
    [OutputCache(Duration=30, Location= OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
    public string Index()
    {
        x++;
        return x.ToString();
    }
}
```

Тот же метод, только кэширование ограничено кэшом сервера. В отличие от предыдущего примера здесь уже запрос идет от браузера к серверу, но после кэширования в течение следующих 30 секунд при повторных обращениях к методу данный метод не будет срабатывать: он просто будет отдавать клиенту данные, которые есть в кэше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При повторных обращениях опять же время довольно мало - в данном случае всего 15 миллисекунд.

Хотя время выполнения данного метода очень мало в силу его простоты - простой инкремент переменной, но в реальности методы, естественно, будут намного сложнее, с выборкой из базы данных, обращением к различным ресурсам и сложных вычислениях. И тут кэширование действительно сможет реально оптимизировать работу сервера.

Взято [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/20.1.php)